# How to covert IpAddress items to string c#

Tags: c#, string, linq, casting, ip-address

I have a ListBox that contains a `System.net.IPAddress` and string items. I want to convert them all to strings. I have tried this as shown below but it says it can not cast from IPAddress to string.

```
var List4 = f.listBox4.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
foreach (string i in List4)
{
    cursheet.get_Range(colname + x).Value = i;
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?  No need for linq, casting, etc..

```
foreach (var item in f.listBox4.Items) 
{ 
    cursheet.get_Range(colname + x).Value = item.Text; 
    x++; 
}
```

Or, if you want the value:

```
foreach (var item in f.listBox4.Items) 
{   
    cursheet.get_Range(colname + x).Value = item.Value; 
    x++; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var List4 = f.listBox4.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString())
```